# Difference between scale_pos_weight values and max_delta_step in xgb.boost method while dealing with highly imbalanced data of two classes

Tags: r, boost, parameters, xgboost

I have hugely imbalanced data where around 96% is class 1 and the rest is class 2, I read a lot online to solution to above problem, In XGBOOST documentation they suggested scale_pos_weight and max_delta_step to deal with imbalanced data, can someone tell me how do they prevent misclassification  and what is the difference between the two.